# Detox field CFBundleIdentifier not found inside Info.plist

Tags: react-native, expo, detox

Following Expo usage guide for detox and getting error below when running detox test.

Using:

```
"detox": "^10.0.10",
"detox-expo-helpers": "^0.6.0",
"expo-detox-hook": "^1.0.10"
```

IPA made with :

```
xcode v 9.4.1
expo v 31.0.6
```

Also tried IPAs built with xcode v10 and expo v 32.0.0, same error.

Error:

```
Error: field CFBundleIdentifier not found inside Info.plist of app binary at /Users/admin/Desktop/expo-test/bin/gogonow.app
at SimulatorDriver.getBundleIdFromBinary (/Users/admin/Desktop/expo-test/node_modules/detox/src/devices/drivers/SimulatorDriver.js:70:13)
```

Comment: @Andrew the official detox docs on usage with expo

Comment: https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Expo.md

Comment: Check out this answer I gave recently going through the steps of how to setup detox with expo https://stackoverflow.com/a/54834078/5508175

Comment: Thanks! I was downloading my app build from Expo instead of Expo's Client tool.  Your answer made it a lot more clear.  Tests are running now but crashing out with this: 
`Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        43.191s
Ran all test suites matching /e2e/i with tests matching "^((?!:android:).)*$".
child_process.js:644
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: node_modules/.bin/jest "e2e" --config=e2e/config.json--maxWorkers=1 '--testNamePattern=^((?!:android:).)*$' ` 
I don't have any android tests.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53929106/5508175 the first part of this answer explains your question about android, if your tests fail that is pretty much what they say.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'll try and make a pull request to clarify/fix some things with the detox expo guide.

Answer (score -1):

Try with in the detox configuration
you should take care of .app path, xcodeproj path, Scheme[The app name] and the info.plist path.

This should work..